# PHP set_time_limit no effect

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have a very painful slow script that gets lots of data from MySQL and creates a large report out of it that it serves to the user at the end as application/force-download.

Long story short, on production server it keeps terminating after about 30 seconds (quite consistently) and spitting out an empty file instead. On development server it works fine, but it does take significantly longer to execute - about 90 seconds. Just to be 'safe', I set my php.ini file to `max_execution_time = 2000` and also run `set_time_limit(4000)` in the beginning of my script (numbers way over the expected completion time, but just to be sure ;)).

What could be causing my web server to ignore the time limits I set and quit on me after only 30 seconds?

Edit: one thing I know for sure is that it takes MySQL portion of the code 8-9 seconds to complete, and it successfully gets past that point every time.

Comment: What about the time limit on the mysql side?  and in the php.ini for mysql functionality?

Comment: Check your memory limits as well. You might be exhausting your max memory.

Comment: Are your error logs enabled? If so, they will give us a clue as to what is happening, what do the logs say?

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` output to see what the 'local' setting is for max_execution_time. PHP can have multiple .ini files (for command line and web-based execution) and it's possible you modified the wrong one.

Comment: memory limit is 512MB by default and I just set it to -1.

Comment: phpinfo() says max_execution_time = 2000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the PHP safe_mode.

Try to do a

```
die(ini_get('max_execution_time'))
```

to read the value after you have called the `set_time_limit(0);` to see if actually it get overwrited.

If it gets overwrited to 0 and your script still dies then the cause could be somewhere else in your code

Comment: You probably mean `max_execution_time` http://php.net/info.configuration#ini.max-execution-time Edit: I mean `safe_mode` :X http://php.net/ini.sect.safe-mode#ini.safe-mode

Comment: safe_mode appears to be off. memory_limit is successfully set to -1.

Comment: @salty: sorry of course I meant max_execution_time. +1 @king for correction

Comment: die() trick shows that max_execution_time is successfully changed to a larger number.

Comment: @salty: then your script dies not for the time limit but because there are some other errors somewhere in the code

Comment: @yes123 you are right, it was not a timeout problem, it was something rather different.

Comment: @salty: glad that helped (and that you picked the answer) Cheers