# Several long running php scripts on wamp

Tags: php, wamp

Is there a reason why I can't run two or more scripts in parallel in a local host environment? They just simply stop without any error message.

Comment: and how do you start the scripts?

Comment: @JanPrieser simply from a web browser, separate tabs

Comment: @RegisteredUser I don't think the code is relevant here, each script runs just fine on their own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcp connections have connection timeouts. after some idle time without data on the wire the connection closes and thus the script stops.

php has time_limits additionaly to prevent high cpu usage. but this limit is not directly related to actual seconds but to uses cpu cycles.

for long running scripts its better to run the from command line instead of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

write `set_time_limit(0)` on the top of you php page and try again

Try below link:

[PHP set_time_limit limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518439/php-set-time-limit-limit)

[PHP set_time_limit no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193104/php-set-time-limit-no-effect)

May be it is helpful to you.

Comment: as you can see in the comments each script runs fine on their own so you could assume I am already using the time limit setting

Comment: ok, did you check the error log?

Comment: Yes. "without any error message" it's in my question.